# Cassandra cluster: some nodes reporting "no other nodes seen", despite identical configuration

Tags: java, hadoop, cassandra

I'm trying to set up an 8 node development cluster.

I made minimal changes to the configuration.  I set one of the nodes as the seed on all the nodes.

3 of the nodes connect to the seed, but 4 more do not.

I have checked that all the non-connecting nodes can access the IP of the seed (they're even on the same subnet).  My network is ok.  I verified all the IPs are correct.

A non-connecting node clearly accesses the seed:

> INFO 17:30:16,272 Starting Messaging Service on port 7000
>
> INFO 17:30:16,281 JOINING: waiting for ring and schema information
>
> INFO 17:30:46,290 JOINING: getting bootstrap token

But then it decides it cannot connect:

> No other nodes seen!  Unable to bootstrap. ...  Otherwise, you need to determine
> why the seed being contacted has no knowledge of the rest of the
> cluster.  Usually, this can be solved by giving all nodes the same
> seed list

What could this be?  Is there a limit on the number of nodes?

Comment: Turns out I had iptables blocking outbound connections on some of those machines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recommended startup procedure for a new cluster is to start the seed nodes first and then begin to start the other nodes, waiting two minutes in between adding each node.  If you add multiple nodes to a cluster at the same time, or you don't start the seed nodes first, you can wind up with issues like the ones you describe.

Comment: May I ask you which are the seed nodes? Thank you very much!

Comment: The seed nodes are specified in cassandra.yaml for each node (and you should use the same list for every node).